# Trigger or Transaction for multi table data update on new Insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables with names `table1`, `table2` and `table3`.

And skeletons are like below

[image: table1]

[image: table2]

[image: table3]

table1 contains `username` and `password` data. `Table2` contains his relation with other users.

So my requirement is when a user is registered, values will be inserted to `table1`. And user also will send list of other users to specify his references. For example when `u1` is addded he has sent `[u2, u3, u5]`. As `u2 and u3` are already registered those two users should be added to `table2` as below. In `table2` `u1 - u5` should be added whenever `u5` is registered.

So I am maintaing `table3` to maintain unregistered users.

To be precise here is what I am trying to do.

when some user is added in `table1` want to raise a trigger that will check `table3` `field_2` value with newly inserted value. Whatever rows are matching should be inserted into `table2` as in `u2` and `u3` case.

Here is what I have tried but I am blurred on how to proceed further

```
create trigger transaction_state after update on table1
      begin 
    insert into table2
       select * from table1 where field_2 = /* newly updated */;
      end;
```

Comment: Your table design does not convince me. Looks like you can reference users that do not exist, so you could not use foreign key constraints. Why not create every user in `table1`, even if they have not registered yet, and maintain a flag if a user is registered? This would allow to keep all references in one table (`table2` or `table3`) and create foreign key references to `table1`.

Comment: @PeterLang That would be cool :) But the problem is the table1 layout is fixed and I could not add a column to it, that is third party server table structure.

Comment: When would a record be inserted in table3? would it be after a record is inserted in table1?

Comment: @DipenduPaul Yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your input, I think there are two triggers to be written,

1. On Insert Trigger on `table3`, which would check if `field_2` is already registered. If yes, then the record (field_1, field_2) would be inserted in `table2`.
2. On Insert Trigger on 'table1', which would select all rows where `uid` appears as `field_2` and inserts all such rows to `table2`.

Let me know if this make sense and inline with your requirement and also the feasibility of it given that you are working third party database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER INSERT ON table3
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
             INSERT INTO table2
             SELECT NEW.field_1, NEW.field_2
               FROM table1
               WHERE table1.uid = NEW.field_2

    END;




CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
    AFTER INSERT ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO table2
                 SELECT table3.field_1, table3.field_2
                   FROM table3
                   WHERE table3.field_2 = NEW.uid

        END;
```

Comment: Thanks, Does FOR EACH run on each and every row in table or only newly inserted?

Comment: statement followed by `For Each ROW` runs for only newly inserted rows, once for each row inserted. You can take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html for more.